# How can I connect to a server through JavaScript where my PHP program is housed?

Tags: php, javascript, android, html, cordova

I am writing an Android App, and already have a working program written in HTML and PHP. Using the two, they contact an API with a user customized lookup on the html page, which then sends to the PHP page, contacts the API with the customized search, gets a result, and the php outputs to a html page again.

I know PHP cannot work on Android, but I plan on using PhoneGap. With PhoneGap, I can run JavaScript, HTML, and CSS supposedly. I have also read that a solution with Android being unable to understand PHP is to connect to a server (my computer) which can run the php for me, and then output it in a way the phone can understand.

My plan is to use JavaScript, which PhoneGap can understand, to connect to my computer, and have it run the PHP and output the page in HTML which again, PhoneGap can understand.

If this is absurd, please let me know... Otherwise I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could push me in the right direction in a JavaScript function that would allow me to authenticate myself, connect to my computer, and tell it I'd like to use a certain PHP file.

Comment: PHP is server side... there cannot be any conflicts with android

Comment: @Austin I'm glad that I was correct in this aspect. Do you have any knowledge of connecting to servers, authenticating the connection, or selecting a php file to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the exact same problem when developing our application for Android as well as for iOS. Like Austin told you already you have to make use of AJAX.

[W3schools - AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

I recommend you however not to use jquery if it's only needed for a few simple things because it's fairly heavy because of the big script it has to load. So if you can reduce the amount of code, please do so by learning the real JavaScript instead of jQuery.

Also, what we did is writing our own APIRequest.js object. When calling this object like so:

```
var result = new APIRequest('functionname', {param1:value, param2:value})
```

This is a fairly easy approach to connect to your php which will run off course on your server somewhere in a foreign country or your pc. 
As you can see we insert a functionname, we have developed our API as a fairly simple OOP php thingy that allows us to put a functionname.php in a certain folder and it will be read by de script and then select that function. Database connections and stuff like that will be aranged in the index of the api. With this approach you can make special functions, server-side, for every unique handling.

I am telling you this because you are making use of JavaScript. I'd like you to understand that it is not safe! It as as safe as a JavaScript application on your computer. It is possible for a hacker to download the .apk to his computer, run it in the simulator on his pc and make edits through his console. And thus meaning, he can change your whole code (at least, the JavaScript part). So make sure you try to make this as safe a possible, with keys and stuff like that. Also, try to do as much logic as possible on your server, so the logic can't be changed. Only the input parameters to your API.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Why would you avoid suggesting jQuery? jQuery Mobile is one of the most powerful phone js frameworks available. Do you suggest that he write all interface commands (like swipe, which is handled in jQuery Mobile) himself? Just because jQuery is overused and many times used incorrectly does not mean that it doesn't have its place in efficient coding.

Comment: Read again. "I recommend you however not to use jquery if it's only needed for a few simple things because it's fairly heavy" -> "...a few simple things..." So I'm not saying he shouldn't, I'm saying, if you are only going to use it for a simple ajax request. Don't! Also, with jquery mobile you are restricted with your code. You don't have full control.

Comment: Additionally, and I'm not trying to pick apart your answer, but just for information's sake - As long as he has a solid server side in place, a hacking attempt is nothing to worry about. jQuery Mobile minified is very small and does not impact load time too heavily.

Comment: It's not about the hacking. It's about inserting values you don't want to have in your function. For example, you create a function iWonThePrice() *very unlikely, it's for example only*. And you have to insert a 0 or a 1 in order to set the "win variable" in your database. What if the hacker is in your JavaScript code and adds the '1' manually? It's the JavaScript hacking I'm talking about. Invalid input through console. About the jQuery mob, I noticed differently.

Comment: Right, by hacking I meant data injection. But with a strong server side, this is nothing to worry about. Client<->Server Session keys should keep it secure.

Comment: Also wanted to add apart from the minified version of jquery mobile, JQM also allows us to further minify by building specific modules.. Here you can get more info http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: @Austin you can not have session keys on an Android device. At least, not with Cordova or a program like that. It sucks, I know. But It's not possible (I hope they will release an update soon)

Answer (score 2):

Here you would need to use AJAX. jQuery has a great wrapper function called `$.ajax` that makes most of the process pretty simple and straightforward.

AJAX will send an asynchronous request to any file (in your case a php file) and fire a callback function with the data it receives.
(synchronous is also possible, but not recommended as it will make your application hang until the request is complete. [More on why this is not recommended](http://ajaxblog.com/archives/2005/05/25/synchronous-requests-bad))

Some good reads on the subjects covered here:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/
- http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Comment: I currently do not have a static IP. With this call, can it interpret "localhost" for development, until I upload it to a permanent server?

Comment: Yes, as long as the file is local (remote files would require `jsonp`). So if you are developing on localhost, and calling to localhost, there should be no problems.

Comment: when you say remote files would require jsonp, do you mean eventually I'd have to rewrite the app essentially for jsonp? I couldn't just place the actual IP of the machine where "localhost" was?

Comment: No, jsonp is a method very similar to AJAX, but for cross-domain transfers. If you are on MyAndroidApp.com/index.html and call to MyAndroidApp.com/getstuff.php - no problem, AJAX is what you use.

Comment: Jsonp won't work (at least, not at our project). We added ||| header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json'); ||| to our code. This made it work.

Comment: You wouldn't need to utilize jsonp if you are communicating on the same domain, you would just normal AJAX

Comment: But you probably aren't in your appliation since it will be used on a different 3G or wifi network. And thus meaning, it's a different domain. It's best to do it right, also on localhost. So you don't have to edit everything when you think it's ready to get distributed. (We had this experience, not funny :) )

Comment: Ok maybe I'm missing something here, what exactly is the route of communication between? If it is between phone and remote server, you need jsonp. If it is from phone to local files on that phone, then it is regular AJAX. If it is on a domain to that domain, it is AJAX

Answer (score 1):

The basic technology you want to use is AJAX, which is the term for making server calls over HTTP from Javascript.  You pass data to and from the server in XML (the X in AJAX) or perhaps in another encoding, such as JSON.

You'll need a dedicated PHP file on the server that will understand the data you send in the AJAX post and instead of generating HTML generates the XML/other format your Javascript will consume.

Your best bet would probably be to create a browser app that communicates with your server via AJAX, and when that is working port it to PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy. Just do a GET request to the PHP page and parse the result. Create a function to make it easier:

```
function httpGet(theUrl){
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Then, you can call it and obtain the resultant HTML code.

```
var url = 'http://yourpage/index.php?a=something&b=otherthing';
var page = httpGet(url);
```

Comment: you say that I would obtain the resultant html code? I've never used the XMLHttpRequest() function, but it seems I would be getting an xml response.... clarification?

Comment: xmlHttp.responseText will give you the HTML code of the page generated by the PHP you request. Try it!