# Handling authentication for PhoneGap app from CakePHP

Tags: jquery, api, cakephp, cordova

I am building a simple app built in PhoneGap that uses a REST API to load in data from my website on the server (because you can't run PHP inside PhoneGap).

An example for listing some data might be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myserver.com/posts/index.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i=0,total=data.length; i<total; i++)
        { 
            console.log(data.Post.title[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

This is fine and the returned data can be used in my PhoneGap app. However let's say that the post list requires you to be logged in...

How would I handle this? Because unlike a normal authentication request whereby it redirects to the login form, in my JSON world this would not happen. In fact what happens is the **actual HTML login form gets returned which then causes an error because my JavaScript is expecting JSON and not HTML.**

Is there a best practice for handling this, such as if authentication requested then load the login form view in the PhoneGap app instead of returning the HTML login form from the app as it's currently doing? Perhaps sending a auth request via JSON?

As an example a simple JSONized method looks like:

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
    $this->set('_serialize', array('posts'));
}
```

And as stated earlier I can protect this method in the `beforeFilter` by **not** passing the method name into the `$this->Auth->allow()`. So I'm presuming I would need to do something clever in the beforeFilter to know if the request is JSON and if so then check if the method requires authorisation and then if so either send back an error (instead of the HTML form as Cake usually does via the AuthComponent) in JSON or allow access.

**UPDATE: 13th Jan 2012**

After doing some research on this subject more, I've looked at the Forrst API as they seem to have built effectively what I am looking to build in terms of a RESTful API.

For example they have a call like: https://forrst.com/api/v2/post/comments?tiny_id=HUD this is basically saying display the comments for post with tiny id of HUD. What you will get returned is the following if you are not authenticated:

```
{"resp":{"error":"this method requires authentication"},"stat":"fail","in":0.0903,"authed":false,"authed_as":false,"env":"prod"}
```

Now the interesting part is EVEN if I am logged into Forrst I will still get that error message because it's not looking at my session rather it's expecting a token of some kind to authenticate the actual request. e.g. `?access_token=550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000`

**So the main question here I guess, is how do I build this into my Cake App? The plan is as follows:**

In my app it would have redirected you to the login page regardless if you have requested it via AJAX or in the browser. **Forrst handles both and ALWAYS returns JSON errors when calling it's API and doesn't return HTML ever!** This is what I want to achieve in my implementation. I have added an access_token column to my users table (which changes whenever anyone updates their password for security reasons). The next step is to A) check for this access token for protected methods and either allow or deny if it's correct and then B) I need someway of handling when no token exists or is incorrect and sending the correct error status instead of the HTML login form.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are building an app for Forrst itself? Or are you using Forrst as your user management system? I do have experience with Cordova (Phonegap) and CakePHP, so I might be able to help you, but the question isn't 100% clear to me. Can you share a link to the exact API you are using? Because the only thing I can find about this API is https://forrst.com/api but it seems as an API to access their posts, instead of a User Management System. So I don't understand the link between your first code snippet which uses `myserver.com`, and `forrst.com` used later on.

Comment: Sorry I'm just using Forrst as an example of what I am trying to create in terms of API capability. In particular the authentication parts of the JSON returned. **I'm not using ANYTHING from Forrst.**

Comment: ok, check out my answer. I hope it will help you in some way :)

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem with our application, built in Phonegap as well (now called Cordova). It was a real pain to get the authentication to work, but eventually we managed to get it working by using the Facebook API, but I assume you don't want to use Facebook.

So, what you can do is simply check if it is an XMLHttpRequest by running the following piece of code:

**PostsController - index()**

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax() == 1){
    // This is an Ajax call
    $this->layout = 'json';
    $this->set('data', array('data', 'to', 'parse'));
} else {
    // This is the normal request
    # do the stuff you want to do here as usual
}
```

But since this will ask you to login, because it is not in the `$this->Auth->allow()` list it will not even get there unless you are logged in. So what you need to do is make a new `AjaxController` which handles the first request. Simply put the code posted above in the `beforeFilter` and do your magic from there. From there you can simply check if someone is logged in and what the current state of the user is. If he is logged in and you want to return the data. You can call the Model you need or call the controller function with `requestAction('/path/to/what/i/need')` where the path you need could be declared in a post variable you sent in the Ajax call.

In the `ajax layout` you can tell to `json_encode` the `$data` which will then be parsed correctly.

**App**

Now in your JavaScript, you will get some data. Let's say you structure your returned JSON string with the following keys: `status` and `data`.

Let's say `status` has been set to `auth` in the returned JSON, you know you need to authenticate, so you can show a login form which then handles all that stuff. Just make a nice login view in the App, so you can control every aspect of it and hopefully make it more safe.

If `status` is set to `success` you can then show all the posts accordingly.

I have an answer to another topic where I show how we created our own API, maybe that can help you in some way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422866/1110760

**warning** JavaScript seems to be safe in the Phonegap application, but it is not! Anybody can download the .apk file from it's Android device and open it in the `Android emulator` who is then able to view all the JavaScript and HTML code. So be very careful with the data you are going to code directly into the JavaScript and how your API is accessible.

---

*I know my answer is kinda vague, so if you need additional information regarding this answer, please ask!*

Comment: This seems very manual... Could I not add something in the AppController to append JSON requests with additional data such as status, authentication etc? As otherwise I am breaking convention by calling another controller to call a method in another.

Comment: @Cameron You could do the checks in your controller or make a component which handles this stuff. Something like a ApiComponent with a main function called `isApi()` so you can check if it is an Api call or not. And `setApi` if you want to force it to be an API call. There are many many approaches. But I would recommend using a component in your case, since you have a really good point not breaking the conventions :) But you will end up with if-statements after all. Because you need safe JSON output instead of html output.

Comment: Still not sure how I would jump in before the login form is returned as HTML, and instead pass the correct error data as JSON. Is there a way to globally add this to JSON requests? As checking for just Ajax calls is not good practice as I use Ajax for other things so it would conflict.

Comment: You could set the default `$this->Auth->allow()` so it would get to the correct method. Then in the method itself set the `$this->Auth->deny()` if you need to, and call the `parent::beforeFilter()`. Might me a little hack, but I am sure it works. I would recommend using a new ApiController then. Because you are dealing with different kind of outputs. So just call the right Models with their methods. Fat models, skinny controllers. I will share this question with some CakePHP guys, perhaps they can help you since they know everything about Cake :)

Comment: @Cameron perhaps you'd like to add me on skype or something. And have a little brainstorm session about the subject?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can understand from this is that you need some way to return some error message like login required in json format if the user is not logged in.  What you can do is you can built a function like:

```
    public function index ($token=NULL)
{
  if($token != NULL)
  {
   // call some method to check if token is valid
   // do required processing 
  }
  else
{
  $response=array('response'=>'failure','message'=>'Login required');
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

In ajax call:

```
 url: 'http://myserver.com/posts/index.json/'+token;
```

In the user table, at time of user registration, simple generate some accesstoken and store 
it in a column say 'accesstoken'.

This token is returned when user logs in.

So you can add it to your ajax call while sending the request.

Say showPosts method in posts controller in your ajax call
http://yourdomain.com/posts/showPosts 
then

```
$method=$this->action; //this fetches the name of the method called                                                   
$Mmethods =array('showPosts','test2'); // methods requiring login                                                               
if(in_array($method,$Mmethods)) {                                  
$this->params array will give you all the parameters passed in URL.
//Fetch the access token from this array if it is set in 'url' index //of this array.                          
//if token is found, run sql query whether it exists in database or //not, else return response with errors and exit;}
```

Comment: $method=$this->action;                                                      $Mmethods =array('test1,''test2');  //array containing names of methods which require access token                                                                                       In beforeFilter() function of your controller, you can do this:  if(in_array($method,$Mmethods)) { //check for access token //if token is not found, return response with errors and exit;  }

Comment: Could you show a more fuller example? Not really understanding how this would work. Thanks.

Comment: Beforefilter() method is called before calling every other method in the controller. So if user access token is not valid, we will use the exit; statement to stop passing control to the requested method in the controller. On the other hand, if it is valid, control will pass to the requested method in the controller.                            Are you performing the rqeuired action in some controller in cakephp or somwhere  else?

Answer (score 2):

For clarification reasons: Do your users need to be "logged-in" to view the returned posts in every case, or only some posts require users to be logged in? Do you have control over the script on the other side `(index.json)`?

From my understanding right now I would use a page in the PhoneGap app to "log-in" then store and send the information along with the request to the server `index.json` or better a php script that can process and return the appropriate `json` string. Basically how Session Cookies work in a typical browser.

Another option is you could modify the `index.json` to return a `json` string containing a message that you could catch, read, and process in PhoneGap then if needed show the user a login form within your app, then do the same as the paragraph above.

I'm willing to help with code and examples, however your current post is vague on your current code and what is returned from the server.

Comment: The index.json was just an example. But basically I need to know if a method requires authentication and if so then pass back this information to my app so that I do the login stuff. It's currently passing back the login form itself which is what I want to stop. Another problem is that if I add some extra JSON to say whether user is logged in or not, I only want to care about this for protected methods if that makes sense. Code examples would appreciated thanks.

Comment: Regarding what is returned. If the method is not protected then it just returns a simple json object for the posts. If it is protected then my Cake app is returning the actual HTML login view HTML.

Comment: If you take a look at my updated post above you can see I have referenced the Forrst API. This is what I am trying to achieve effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, this will do the trick:

The code snippet uses a named parameter together with `is('ajax')` to determine a json request, and also checks if the user is not already logged in. Then it only sends a json error if the requested action needs authentication:

First, put this in your `beforeFilter()` in `AppController`:

```
//see if request is json (json is sent by adding a named param e.g. posts/index/json:1
//if so also check that user not already logged in
if (!empty($this->params['named']['json']) && $this->request->is('ajax') &&  !$this->Auth->user())
{
    //see if the action needs authentication
    $requiresAuth = !in_array($this->params['action'], $this->Auth->allowedActions);
    if ($requiresAuth)
    {
        //send json response
        $response = array('error' => 
            array(
                'code' => 123,
                'message' => 'authError',
            )
        );
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }
}
```

To make a request json, add `/json:1` to your path (e.g. `http://myserver.com/posts/index/json:1` as a named $_GET parameter).
In each controllers `beforeFilter()`, make sure to first add allowed actions to `$this->Auth->allow` *before* calling `parent::beforeFilter()`.

If you are using a more advanced authentication with Access Control Lists (ACL), see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html, you also need to know if the action is allowed in ACL:

```
//the group_id to check permission for (must exist)
$group_id = 8; //your group_id
$group = array(
    'model' => 'Group',
    'foreign_key' => $group_id
);
$actionPath = $this->name . '/' . $this->params['action'];
$requiresAclAuth = $this->Acl->check($group, $actionPath);
```

To see if authentication is needed for ACL:

```
if ($requiresAclAuth && $requiresAuth)
{
    //send json response
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery ajax() function gives you the ability to pass login information along with the request by use of username: and password: (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), use these and handle auth failures in error:

Comment: How would my app know when to request authentication though? As its currently just returning the HTML form to the PhoneGap app.

Comment: Are you saying that if your ajax call is not passing the auth parameters, and authentication is required, you get bounced bakt to the original html login page without any indication that authentication is required?